# Messed-up cursor after kernel upgrade for Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, cursor

I'm runing Kubujtu 14.04, and because of its limitations I needed to upgrade the kernel to version 4.9.  The upgrade seems to have worked except for one glitch: the cursor appears as a smaller arrow with a patterned rectangular box underneath it.  How can I get the correct cursor back without disrupting everything else?  Nothing in System Settings seems to help.  I can change the cursor appearance, but the new cursor has exactly the same problem.  I tried to get a snapshot, but the snapshot doesn't show the cursor.

Comment: You might have more luck with Kubuntu 16.04 with an officially-supported HWE kernel (4.13 or 4.15 are available) or with Kubuntu 18.04 with its official default kernel (4.15).

Comment: I've always upgraded to the latest Kubuntu at the first opportunity.  But like surprisingly many others, I've stuck with 14.04 because the later versions removed a feature I use heavily: different wallpapers on different desktops.  If that's ever restored, I'll upgrade in a heartbeat.